# C++ Doxygen - why are only template classes generating documentation?

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

If I declare a class in a header, **no `Doxygen` entry is generated**. If I define the class, still in a header, an entry is generated. However, only templated classes seem to generate proper documentation (including the brief) whether I use `@brief` or `QT autobrief`, `@class/@struct/`, etc., any variant of `///`, `/**`, `/\**!`, etc. and couldn't find anything that made a difference. I have also tried adding a few tags I didn't think were related, like `@file`; then I turned on `EXTRACT_ALL`, tried `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C`, etc.

The template parameter itself doesn't need to be used in any way to cause documentation to be generated. In fact, the template struct only needs to be declared for both an entry and its brief description to appear, unlike the non-template version.

What am I missing? I'm new to `Doxygen` and not really sure what details are relevant.

```
...
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       =
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        =
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    =
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = YES
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 4
ALIASES                =
TCL_SUBST              =
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  =
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      =
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = YES
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = YES
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = NO
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       =
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    =
LAYOUT_FILE            =
CITE_BIB_FILES         =
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           =
INPUT                  = ../include ../README.md
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          =
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = ../include/util/
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       =
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        =
EXAMPLE_PATH           =
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       =
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             =
INPUT_FILTER           =
FILTER_PATTERNS        =
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS =
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = ../README.md
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = NO
REFERENCES_RELATION    = NO
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
SOURCE_TOOLTIPS        = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = NO
CLANG_OPTIONS          =
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line looks suspiciously like you're not allowing doxygen to process your implementation files at all.  No wonder only items defined in the headers show up.

```
INPUT                  = ../include ../README.md
```

Comment: True, but I was talking about declarations and definitions that were in a header. Would adding unrelated source files help, or must the definition be in a source file for comments to be parsed? If so, why does this not apply to template structs? Sorry if this is obvious. My M.O. is normally to forward-declare structs in one header, define them and their members in 'sub-headers', and put implementations for each in the sources. So far I'm only interested in adding documentation to the forward declarations, although everything else will happen eventually.

Comment: If you could explain why this is the case I would be happy to mark your answer... sorry to waste your time but I don't see why a templated declaration and/or definition should be parsed by Doxygen but not an untemplated one, whether or not it's found in a header file.

Comment: @JohnP: I guess I was thinking more about the members rather than the types themselves, so my answer may not actually solve your issue.  Anyway, there's no such thing as a template class forward-declaration.  The first definition of the template may lack a class body, but it still defines the template -- its template parameters and default values for each -- and usage and specializations are already permitted by this definition (due to two-phase lookup).

Comment: @JohnP: In short, I believe that thinking about this as "templated classes" vs non-template classes is wrong.  Doxygen sees a template, fully defined, and therefore emits documentation for the template.  The fact that no class body is given is irrelevant, because documentation isn't for the class.  It's for the template itself.

Comment: Why is a fully-defined (non-template) class that happens to live in a header any different? I can accept that the existence of the definition is the difference and not the template component, but I think I'm still missing something. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @JohnP: Aren't you seeing, consistently, that Doxygen generates documentation when it sees the definition?  (This makes sense, because there can be many declarations but only one definition, see One-Definition-Rule).  Your non-template class is documented when Doxygen comes across the class body.  Your template is documented when Doxygen comes across it (without a class body, a template declaration still defines the template, just not a specialization)

Comment: As I've said - I can make the definition exist solely in a header file, no source file necessary. And yet, Doxygen emits no output for such a class/struct. This is not "definition vs. no definition".

Comment: @JohnP: Then your question is confusing me.  You wrote "If I declare a class in a header, no Doxygen entry is generated. If I define the class, still in a header, an entry is generated."  To me, that sounds line "definition vs no definition".  Can you clarify, please?

Comment: Okay. When I say "declaration", I mean like a forward declaration: `struct abc;` When I say "definition", I mean `struct abc {...};` Both of these can go in a header. If there are Doxygen comments above either, but the filename ends with ".hpp", Doxygen ignores them (unless of course `template<...>` appears before `struct`.) If the latter, `struct abc {...}` is simply cut and pasted into a file that ends with ".cpp", comments and all, Doxygen happily emits documentation. This assumes you have enabled both files as input, which I knew, but what I didn't know is why the extension would matter.

Comment: This question seems to be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946846/use-file-or-class-for-documenting-classes-in-doxygen?rq=1 ... it's not a duplicate but someone who uses forward declarations is having trouble getting Doxygen to emit documentation depending on the file type. Could this be a bug of some kind, or a legitimate choice to ignore certain things unless they appear in a translation unit, something like that?

Comment: @JohnP: What you're missing is that `template <typename T> class X;` is a definition, while `class Y;` is not a definition (both are declarations).  The file extension shouldn't matter, as long as Doxygen maps both to the C++ parser (Doxyfile setting: `EXTENSION_MAPPING`), but seeing the definition would.  Your question said "If I define the class, still in a header, an entry is generated."  Now you say " If there are Doxygen comments above either, but the filename ends with ".hpp", Doxygen ignores them"  Which is it?

Comment: "`class Y;` is not a definition" -- no, but `class Y {};` is, right?